# Should I worry about attaching a lot of unneeded event handlers/listeners?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a site with many jQuery event handlers on each page, all in one large .js file.

This means that for any page, the majority of event handlers are for HTML that doesn't exist and won't be used at all.

Will this ding my performance at all?

**Edit:** As an example, most event handlers will be done something like this:

```
$(".page").on("click", ".notes .add", function(){ ... });
```

Because `.on()` works for new elements, will it always be wasting processing power, or will that only come in to effect when the DOM changes after an ajax call? So to further clarify my question, I guess I should break it down in to two parts.

1. If there is a performance ding, when will that happen? (Always, on any event, on DOM changes only, on load only).
2. Is the ding enough to worry about? How do I measure this? If there are a thousand such listeners, will the ding be measured in seconds, milliseconds, microsecond? I get that I can load the page and see how it 'feels' but I'd like to have an idea if I'm building the whole thing wrong before I start!

Comment: Well if you don't do something like `if($(element).length){ //handle here } ` you're creating unnecessary overhead which will also produce an error saying that `element could not be found`

Comment: Well, jQuery will try to find the elements, it won't succeed and hence won't do anything with the handlers. Only you can test whether this actually has an impact on the performance of your site/script. Obviously it is doing *something*, which is more than nothing, but that does not mean you will notice a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It largely depends on the markup, but in general, it's a good idea to remove unnecessary event handlers if they are not being used.

jQuery events are attached to elements using the Sizzle selection engine. That means a call to `$('a').click()` still has to traverse the entire DOM searching for links. Since your elements do not exist, no events will be bound, but that doesn't preclude jQuery from having to search for the target elements. One way to reduce the workload on jQuery is to test for the presence of a known element, say, a form tag, before binding the necessary events.

```
if ($('form').size() > 0) { 
   // bind events for form here
}
```

It gets even worse if the events are persisted with `.on()`, `.delegate()`, or `.live()` as these will eat up more resources as they are designed to bind to ALL elements, including ones that have yet to be created.

Comment: All the jQuery events will be using `.on()`, sometimes to an object pretty high up the DOM tree (though never all the way up to BODY). How does `.on()` make it worse than a normal event handler?

Comment: @brentonstrine, that's a good point. Using bind() apparently calls on() behind the scenes. That said, a standard bind() or click() method does not pass a selector to on(), so there's no persistence for child elements in that case.

Comment: I don't see why testing the existence of elements before binding the handler has any advantage. In both cases you are searching for the elements. Also, event delegation does not bind to all elements. It binds to one element and then tests whether any descendant elements where the event originated matches the provided selector. Every event handling method calls `.on` behind the scenes btw.

Answer (score 1):

I think it goes without saying that you should only include the JavaScript that you actually need. Any piece of code you don't need is just wasting processing power **but** whether it has a performance impact really depends on your markup / other code / etc.

Instead of worrying about performance, I would worry about **maintainability**. Do you really want to have only one large JavaScript file with all the code for all pages of your site? It will get messy eventually.

---

Regarding: `$(".page").on("click", ".notes .add", function(){ ... });`. It really depends. The nice thing with event delegation is that it only binds *one* event handler to manage *multiple* elements.

Here, it binds the event handler only to `.page`. But the handler is examining *any* click event originating from a descendant of `.page` to see whether the element matches `.notes .add`. It should be obvious that if there are no `.notes .add` elements, this is just unnecessary computation.

But if instead the `.page` element does not even exist, then the event handler won't even be bound, which is ok. jQuery will try to find `.page` elements and will fail. Depending on the complexity of the selector, this can really have an impact (a class name is not complex though).